# paragraph with border

Tags: css

I have paragraphs on a page which i would like to add a border.

```
<p class="valid">paragraph</p>
```

CSS

```
p.valid {
padding:5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The Problem is this displays the paragrph as 100% of the page

I have also tried adding inline-block which wraps the text as i would like, but inline is like float left.

```
p.valid {
padding:5px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you float the element, also set it to [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) any (left) floating elements:

```
p.valid {
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear):

> The `clear` CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `<span>` tag instead of `<p>` because a paragraph is supposed to extend across the entire page, and it looks like `<span>` will help you more with what you're trying to accomplish.